# Infinispan file index cache thread leaks

Tags: java, infinispan

I have a thread leak on a Java application using Infinispan for index file caching. I think it is related to this stack trace (lot of occurrences) :

```
org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: ISPN029019: Cannot load key SimpleKey [/* OBFUSCATED FOR STACKOVERFLOW */] from index.
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.NonBlockingSoftIndexFileStore.lambda$load$17(NonBlockingSoftIndexFileStore.java:601)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading from 0:4936138
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.EntryRecord.readEntryHeader(EntryRecord.java:93)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.IndexNode$LeafNode.getHeaderAndKey(IndexNode.java:1033)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.IndexNode$LeafNode.loadRecord(IndexNode.java:1063)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.IndexNode$ReadOperation$1.apply(IndexNode.java:224)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.IndexNode$ReadOperation$1.apply(IndexNode.java:221)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.IndexNode.applyOnLeaf(IndexNode.java:295)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index.getRecord(Index.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Index.getRecord(Index.java:106)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.NonBlockingSoftIndexFileStore.lambda$load$17(NonBlockingSoftIndexFileStore.java:592)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

This exception should be thrown by `org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.EntryHeader` class at line 42

```
   public EntryHeader(ByteBuffer buffer, boolean oldFormat) {
      if (!oldFormat && buffer.get() != MAGIC) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
      }
      // ...
   }
```

In what direction should I go to solve this problem ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version are you using? It sounds like the data in the store got corrupted somehow. There were quite a few changes introduced in the more recent 13.0 versions that prevent this corruption during a failed shutdown.

Comment: Thanks. Using transaction solved the problem.